# Datediff NULL query

Tags: sql-server, null, datediff

I'm fairly new to SQL and have a question regarding datediff function.

I would like to bring back all accounts where the settled date is between 1 and 180 days of the original due date which I can do as per below.

```
DATEDIFF(DD,odd.[date],sett.[date]) between 1 and 180
```

How do I also include all where the settled date may be NULL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how NULL values are to be interpreted, and the use of the `isnull` function.

If NULL means "today", use

```
DATEDIFF(DD, isnull(odd.[date], getdate()), isnull(sett.[date], getdate()) between 1 and 180
```

If NULL means "never qualifies", use a dummy date that will always disqualify it. The following *should* always return a negative number if either/or both values are null:

```
DATEDIFF(DD, isnull(odd.[date], 'Dec 31, 2100'), isnull(sett.[date], 'Jan 1, 1980') between 1 and 180
```

If some other date value applies, determine and set it as the second value in the appropriate `isnull`.

Answer (score 0):

You can append that in the WHERE clause like following:

```
SELECT * FROM <tables join> 
WHERE DATEDIFF(DD,odd.[date],sett.[date]) between 1 and 180 
OR 
sett.[date] IS NULL
```

Comment: This is assuming that you don't need any date comparison for non-settled values.